# How to find one between two values using Jpa Repository?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

How can I find an object in JpaRepository which value stands between two other values. This is my table in DB:

[image]

What query should I use ? findOneBetweenSinceAndUntil(Long value) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check value between two different fields by using `GreaterThan` and `LessThan` in JPA

```
public T findOneBySinceGreaterThanAndUntilLessThan(Long since, Long until);
```

Including boundary

```
public T findOneBySinceGreaterThanEqualAndUntilLessThanEqual(Long since, Long until);
```

Reference documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-data-jpa-reference.pdf

SQL generated:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.name as name2_0_, user0_.since as since3_0_, user0_.until as until4_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.since>? and user0_.until<?
```